# Why are bullet points breaking my code blocks?

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

#### When I type this:

```
- There are no errors in the console log.
- No errors when ran through JS Hint
- Chrome debugger shows the code executed
- Chrome Elements tab does **not** show the styles as loaded
- `.site-title`'s styles are applied perfectly 
- `.menu-btn` is not applying at all.
- When the *same styles* are added via CSS they apply correctly.

    body > div.site-container > button.menu-btn {
      top: unset;
      right: unset;
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 10px;
      z-index: 100;
      position: fixed;
    }
```

#### The result is:

- There are no errors in the console log.
- No errors when ran through JS Hint
- Chrome debugger shows the code executed
- Chrome Elements tab does **not** show the styles as loaded
- `.menu-btn` is not applying at all.
- When the *same styles* are added via CSS they apply correctly.

  body > div.site-container > button.menu-btn {
    top: unset;
    right: unset;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
  }

---

In order to get my code block to appear correctly I have to add `---` before the code block.

#### When I type this:

```
- There are no errors in the console log.
- No errors when ran through JS Hint
- Chrome debugger shows the code executed
- Chrome Elements tab does **not** show the styles as loaded
- `.site-title`'s styles are applied perfectly 
- `.menu-btn` is not applying at all.
- When the *same styles* are added via CSS they apply correctly.

---
    body > div.site-container > button.menu-btn {
      top: unset;
      right: unset;
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 10px;
      z-index: 100;
      position: fixed;
    }
```

#### The result is:

- There are no errors in the console log.
- No errors when ran through JS Hint
- Chrome debugger shows the code executed
- Chrome Elements tab does **not** show the styles as loaded
- `.site-title`'s styles are applied perfectly
- `.menu-btn` is not applying at all.
- When the *same styles* are added via CSS they apply correctly.

---

```
body > div.site-container > button.menu-btn {
  top: unset;
  right: unset;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
}
```

**Is this a bug or is there a way for me fix this in my markup?**

Comment: Note this has been asked before, and it's because the code is considered part of the bullet and needs to be indented 8 spaces if it is to continue being part of the list, or somehow breaking the code from the list. A simple fix is to put an HTML comment after the bullet points: `<?-- -->`.

Comment: This is annoying. I've come across it before. Another way to break-out of the list without adding anything visual to the post is to use `<p></p>` or `<div></div>` in place of your `---`

Comment: @Turnip Or `<!---->`.

Comment: Thanks! I did some some searching but did not come across that post.

Comment: In the future, consider searching meta similar to searching stackoverflow before asking. For example, [this search strategy](https://www.google.com/search?q=format+code+after+list+site:meta.stackoverflow.com) would get you a decent answer quickly. It's all about use of good key words and selectively searching this site.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels fantastic. I'll definitely search that way from now on. Way better results.

Comment: @JarrodWhitley: glad it helped

Comment: Also, make sure to put a space between `-` and your list item. Two of your list items aren’t correct.

Comment: @Xufox I never thought to try a comment  :facepalm:

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm glad you're glad it helped <3

Comment: This madness must stop

Comment: I think it's interesting that things are getting too crazy for "Hovercraft Full of Eels". I'd love to know the story behind that name lol

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, I'm new to this post, what is this "madness" that you speak of?

Comment: @Orion you should watch some [Monty Python's Flying Circus](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G6D1YI-41ao)

Comment: My google image search for "Hovercraft Full of Eels" had a surprising amount of results https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjMxdXbm8XeAhXRqYMKHaoCD24QjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Feelcult.blogspot.com%2F2016%2F&psig=AOvVaw2ZvS3dxUj8yb-4kGQgkion&ust=1541780932555631